# About Android Sensor how to take count of Sit-up?

Tags: android, sensors

When I use accelerometer Sensor, the result is inaccurate.
Then, I use Gravity sensor and get the same result as use accelerometer sensor.

Someone help me?

#### First, Only Accelerometer Sensor

```
        // Z-axle
        float acceleration = event.values[2];

        if (mStatusDown) {
            if (acceleration > STATUS_UP) {
                mStatusDown = false;
                tv_count.setText(String.valueOf(++count));

            }
        } else {
            if (acceleration < STATUS_DOWN) {
                mStatusDown = true;
            }
        }
```

#### Second

```
        if(event.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){
            float x = event.values[0];
            float y = event.values[1];
            float z = event.values[2];

            if(x - lastX > 0.5 && x > 8 && z - lastZ < -0.5 && z < -5 && !blnCount){
                blnCount = true;
                System.out.println("+1");
                tv_count.setText(String.valueOf(++count));
            }

            if(lastX - x <- 0.5 && x < 4 && z - lastZ > 0.5 && z > 8 && blnCount){
                blnCount = false;
                System.out.println("reset");
            }
```

I'm not familiar with Sensor develop.

#### which Sensor could be used?

- Gyroscope Sensor?
- Accelerometer Sensor?
- Gravity Sensor?

Comment: you should probably provide more details if you want help, for instance- what did you try, code, etc.

Comment: Thank you for you opinion .